# PSALM: Docblock-defined class or interface does not exist

Tags: php, static-code-analysis, psalm-php

I have the following code:

```
namespace Some\Space\Utility;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * @psalm-template T
 */
class SomeAdapter
{
    /**
     * Some method
     *
     * @psalm-param iterable<int, T> $data
     *
     * @psalm-return Collection<int, T>
     */
    public static function doSomething($data): Collection
    {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $data = new ArrayCollection($data);
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Probably I miss something but I got the following error for `@psalm-param`:

> psalm: UndefinedDocblockClass: Docblock-defined class or interface Some\Space\Utility\T does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the function is static. This is the correct solution:

```
    /**
     * Some method
     *
     * @psalm-template T
     * @psalm-param iterable<int, T> $data
     *
     * @psalm-return Collection<int, T>
     */
```

The template has to be defined on the method.